# Absolute positioned div and its content

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser, cross-browser

EDITED: this first version was a false example with false assumptions! See below for new version!

The Setting:

I have 2 absolute positioned divs:

```
<div class="menuSubBack">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="menuSub">
  <ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

with the following styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
.menuSub
{
  position:   absolute;
  top:        0px;
  left:       0px;
  width:      100px;
  overflow:   auto;
  color:      #FFFFFF;
  font-size:  8pt;
  z-index:    99 !important;
}

.menuSub ul
{
  list-style: none;
  padding:    0px;
  margin:     0px;
}

.menuSub ul li
{
  text-align:  center;
  line-height: 25px;
  height:      25px;
  font-size:   12px;
}

.menuSubBack
{
  position:    absolute;
  top:         0px;
  left:        0px;
  width:       100px;
  overflow:    hidden;
  z-index:     1 !important;
  background:  #00FFFF;
}
</style>
```

The problem:

The "menuSub" div has auto generated li tags. The "menuSubBack" later gets javascript generated svg content that needs to get a height to be drawn correctly. You probably already guessed that I need those 2 divs in the same height. I tried to achieve this with jQuery but .height(), .innerHeight() and .outerHeight() all return 0, even for the ul inside the "menuSub" div. Is there any way of getting the correct height? (apart from counting the li elements and sum up fixed heights)

---

EDIT: The example previously seen Is not the correct Problem, so here follows a full sized copy/paste example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .menuSub
      {
        position:   absolute;
        top:        0px;
        left:       0px;
        width:      100px;
        overflow:   auto;
        color:      #FFFFFF;
        font-size:  8pt;
        z-index:    99 !important;
      }

      .menuSub ul
      {
        list-style: none;
        padding:    0px;
        margin:     0px;
      }

      .menuSub ul li
      {
        text-align:  center;
        line-height: 25px;
        height:      25px;
        font-size:   12px;
      }

      .menuSubBack
      {
        position:    absolute;
        top:         0px;
        left:        0px;
        width:       100px;
        overflow:    hidden;
        z-index:     1 !important;
        background:  #00FFFF;
      }

      .menuHover
      {
        position:  absolute;
        top:       20px;
        left:      20px;
        width:     100px;
        z-index:   10;
        display:   none;
        overflow:  visible;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
          $("#targetDiv").height($("#sourceDiv").height());
          $("#hoverDiv").fadeIn("fast");
        }
      );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="hoverDiv"  class="menuHover">
      <div id="targetDiv" class="menuSubBack">&nbsp;</div>
      <div id="sourceDiv" class="menuSub">
        <ul>
          <li>test1</li>
          <li>test2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So the real problem seems to be, that targetDiv and sourceDiv reside inside the hoverDiv which is not visible when loading the page and thus do not get correctly calculated.

Comment: the million dollar question... so far no one has provided a non-complicated answer.

Comment: This works well for me using the provided HTML and Firefox 3.5. Which browser are you using, and how are you generating the <li> tags? Is this done server-side or client-side? Are you sure the height detection code is run *after* you have finished generating the list, and not during execution?

Comment: what is the function of menuSubBack?
and why it must be absolute positioned?

Comment: @rochal: As I pointed out it contains an autogenerated svg. It is intended as a background for menuSub (like the name is indicating).
@samir: all the code is generated server side (except the svg of course). I use the jQuery $(document).ready() function, so I'm pretty sure everything is set up when the height calc is started. I'm a little puzzled as you are right, the simplyfied example is working fine. I'm trying to figure out why it isn't in the full code. I'm extending the example right now to better reach the target setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you hiding these menus? Any element that has a style of `display:none` will return a height of zero. If you have this menu hidden and need a height, then position it to the left, out of the browser viewport (e,g, `left: -10000px`) then when you want to display the menu, reposition it inside the viewport (e.g. `left: 0px`). Using this method the height of the element should be accurate.

Comment: That seems to be the problem indeed. I simply have a problem with the solution: I want to let the menu fade in on mouse over, that doesn't work if the menus are already visible... Thinking of it I might just hide the menus after creating the svg. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Glad I could help... all that is required is that the element is visible when you determine its height, after that you can hide it without problem.